# Can a CRON script log on a user

Tags: raspberry-pi-os-bookworm

I am asking if it's possible to log a user on via CRON or Python or BASH

I am aware that you can AUTO LOGIN via Raspberry Pi Configuration and this question is not about this.

I have a situation where my Pi is logging me off automatically and randomly and I don't know why, I only find out when I try to remote in via VNC and I am presented with the Raspberry Pi logon page, so I am looking to see if I can run a script to log me back on automatically somehow.

FYI:
It's a headless Raspberry Pi 5 running on Debian Bookworm (Raspberry Pi OS version) and running apache and some other Python data collecting jobs via CRON
I only even remote in using VNC to the desktop or via ssh

Comment: *"my Pi is logging me off automatically and randomly"*. You've probably buggered something with the *"apache and some other Python data collecting jobs"* you've installed - but that is purely a guess. Based on the information you've provided, my ***advice*** would be to start over. If you want an answer, you're going to have to provide more details than you have... you don't even clearly explain **how** you logged on to your system (VNC, SSH, local terminal)?????

Answer (score 0):

No you can't login via `cron` as it isn't a pty session.